# Evaluate Fraction Expression : Subtraction

Tags: java, string, delimiter, fractions, stringtokenizer

I'm creating a fraction class in java. The program take an entire fraction expression and performs the operation based on the operator with a switch statement. I have everything working except when the program is given an expression that is subtraction, i.e., -1/2--1/2. When I test this expression I receive a number format exception. I believe it has something to do with my delimiters in my StringTokenizer but not sure what to do. Any help is appreciated.

```java
String regex = "-?[0-9]+[ \t]*/[ \t]*-?[0-9]+[ \t]*[+-/\\*][ \t]*-?[0-9]+[ \t]*/[ \t]*-?[0-9]+";
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.print("Please enter a fraction expression i.e., -1/2 - -1/4: ");
        String expression = input.nextLine();

        if (!expression.matches(regex)) {
            System.out.println("Not a valid fraction expression");
        }
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(expression, "-/*\t ", true);
        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String token = st.nextToken();
            if (!token.equals(" ") && !token.equals("\t"))
                myList.add(token);
        }

 int num1 = Integer.parseInt(myList.get(0));
        int den1 = Integer.parseInt(myList.get(2));
        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(myList.get(4));
        int den2 = Integer.parseInt(myList.get(6));

        Fraction fraction1 = new Fraction(num1, den1);
        Fraction fraction2 = new Fraction(num2, den2);

        String operator = myList.get(3);

switch (operator) {
            case "+":
                System.out.println(fraction1.add(fraction2));
                break;
            case "-":
                System.out.println(fraction1.sub(fraction2));
                break;
            case "*":
                System.out.println(fraction1.mult(fraction2));
                break;
            case "/":
                System.out.println(fraction1.div(fraction2));
                break;
        }
```

Comment: Read the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)). Delimiters will just separate tokens. With a `, true` they will become tokens also. The error eludes me. Use a debugger to the token you get.

Answer (score 0):

I tested you Code snippet and got it to work when changing the delimiter from
    "-/*\t "
to
    "/*\t "

On another note: You maybe want to return out of the code when the typed in string does not match your expression:

```
    if (!expression.matches(regex)) {
        System.out.println("Not a valid fraction expression");
        return;
    }
```

Comment: I changed the delimiter to what you have above but the program still isn't evaluating a fraction expression that has to do with subtraction i.e. -1/4 --2/3.

Comment: Thats probably because when using Integer division "1/2" you get zero. Try parsing double instead. This way you get datatypes you can use for division.